# JSch getting "invalid privatekey:" while trying to load an RSA private key by KeyPairGenerator

Tags: java, ssh, rsa, jsch

I'm using java.security.KeyPairGenerator to gen an RSA key pair, and then try to load the private key via the KeyPair class provided in Jsch(0.1.49).  The code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String header = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";
    String footer = "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";
    KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator;
    try {
        keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048, new SecureRandom());
        PrivateKey privateKey = keyPairGenerator.genKeyPair().getPrivate();
        String key = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(privateKey.getEncoded()));
        StringBuffer pem = new StringBuffer(header+"\n");
        int len=key.length();
        for( int idx=0 ; idx < len ; idx+= 64 )
            pem.append(key.substring(idx, (idx+64)<len?(idx+64):len)+"\n");
        pem.append(footer);
        String privateKeyStr = pem.toString();
        System.out.println(privateKeyStr);
        com.jcraft.jsch.KeyPair.load(null, privateKeyStr.getBytes(), null);
    } catch (JSchException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The output by System.out:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Then I see exceptions from KeyPair saying it's an invalid private key, I checked the source code of JSch, the exception is due to an **indexoutofbounds** while the data's being parsed. The stacktrace:

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: invalid privatekey: [B@5f2e5f2e
    at com.jcraft.jsch.KeyPair.load(KeyPair.java:809)
    at com.ibm.maestro.common.utils.Test.main(Test.java:149)
```

I'm guessing I can fix this issue by adding/changing some parms while generating the key pair, any clue?  Your help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: May be there are format differences between java.security keys and JSch keys. You can use `KeyPair.genKeyPair(jsch, KeyPair.RSA, myKeySize)` to generate valid keypair

Comment: That won't work, I need to use jsch to login a remote VM who's private key is generated by java.security.KeyPairGenerator ......

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Sun JCA provider will return an DER-encoded unencrypted PKCS #8 structure, rather than an RSAPrivateKey object when you call `PrivateKey.getEncoded()`.

You can use BouncyCastle to give you the key in the format you require:

```
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

import org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMWriter;

public class JSCH {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048, new SecureRandom());
    PrivateKey privateKey = keyPairGenerator.genKeyPair().getPrivate();

    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

    try (PEMWriter pemWriter = new PEMWriter(writer)) {
      pemWriter.writeObject(privateKey);
    }

    String privateKeyStr = writer.toString();
    System.out.println(privateKeyStr);
    com.jcraft.jsch.KeyPair
        .load(null, privateKeyStr.getBytes("US-ASCII"), null);
  }
}
```

There may be a more elegant way to get the encoded key as a byte string. It feels ugly to write it as a string and call `getBytes()`, but perhaps you can look into this.

Example output:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEowIBAAKCAQEA3r29olF+Kul+aHsB28i9x8RiH6OEgIDoqcN4Ph0+bCYBi9lk
E/TVtLXxNxXvvcsK5DyQLZAWj/W0QmvmItndkzcWFojIoS3XT7kFPeC49hPe6g/W
ihM7eS5W3wTzAoljimyMjFUkw9ahShRrL+Dl6ZeqMW5bTwUXgcIFSKNw4iFQJFFO
5G8a1ObAV5iNA1ve5IFntKjCc5WIA4byilBCLcoXCeQNSPwyGVc1Okz22FTAQFzk
9eQthuF3AIAhHcDgf1yxx6RTTMMMSWzIva6xZvTHCKov3CwTLioH1Ri72UT9GAoq
O4hS/CL4Q4m09X6KGicXR86CpQ8TiXD4A+HwkQIDAQABAoIBAQCLYmrvz1VHnzPm
R8ti8NypzN+mctnw3Do8OcDeBcjRPntLO2+f+V9eJVjcItMSjqOzLZ7/lCI6VgRG
aGTsPC+m9xrQYSpDin8pOVvpW94Cx26ARAb6Aoz+CRx9lQhI9xaeQc015/YIwx/N
TrfAj1jwc2Miaa+j5EjQf0x1Jyn1pr41vgC5z2zD+FyNfVOu7Q4rmiEIi3B+QHWg
33YhtJrP2nWEmka6pn0NiYlS3IZRA6tL7DUC62iTfs7vs5M6OCsg9w7Vfq5YGwr3
cm9n+VencsupB4A6b13XZPWhyaImGO7+5TQy4xX9/mT99GoC6L73RX5O4Ehhg++m
NpB8Bt5tAoGBAO+rR0dleFeH4aHtMeLlatjZhSIWcRzXqW/bkeaq4SrhF7h4GC9J
Spih1fjWMznrfcsHxgJyYtZ3OBPMp7DhUZR9WbeqOwpD5Qd0Kr3LovKiX6HTeNKQ
QyPvca0n3z6a72XGqbKonoXhUJ2OKv8pl7nVaBxO9r/YloTLZ5SOMpmHAoGBAO3r
LU6zxBdUzaJ28tuNx2TCJJyLCDSrnZFgyTA+xexk1wpJXOJxmCVBTl5tajYwhjTc
9OMOVGr8qgcblcDOSCy4khZrgStHfjzZBQA8zesR/vNO+nzGxzfzIMSNey7OKtAB
LoKMEe1O1FuxTCiQZveekzZlT3EKDgU809UDvksnAoGANGXF154fiUNz2Or6lRiD
G5WyvZkacavUp1fhtgR15eIARZw77VqgrG31UcnCuU762YCBkddgNHMsF2gO4WTh
aQ1eqADXl47wa4jCL2xt244USlTpfV98zkZzG+AztoQ5Ao9EWoLy5WI1Nbz3OYHm
YgJ+GHJLD/ZSMgYmRxwvg9ECgYBVDs0l4/Lo/HJ/8NKmV6u/hAEezj3ixrAQd2+2
BdswxmRy0wOYGVBxkUV5UNi2AucYIx6Rxl+72BTZca06PwVip6HizhBh7q9dBaFa
EmLz9X0Wc1fuIAq9H/jJDGPLuf1oW+PK3FTUaGhXV62ImweU42Zx/gpGuXeFu9dn
wmzX5QKBgHgbQHqcf36bvwE/zr9jLCOPSkVZpFPYNt6/uUT/Vb4vDPME2/wk1SoU
wV2I3Vj9bLsnkpsP6fOsX3QqGFwlnnpboF/IS9rObTkDZXsKfLJhT5x6xA6USnWC
ZPY8jO4b1RXf3v1mHpkx21dKmY2YvNetzp6OaK8DzPwFM8KUh5GG
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: Duncan, thanks for the answer, I'm totally new to the RSA stuff, tried to google but it's said that the way to convert DER ASN.1 to PEM is base64 encode, then adding header and trailer.

Comment: @user627110 Yes, that is correct. Perhaps you've made a minor error in that part of your code? Maybe edit your question to include the definition of your `encodePEM` method?

Comment: Thanks a lot Duncan, one last question, as I'm new to security area:should DER-encoded unencrypted PKCS #8 structure considered violates the security convention or not secure?  I'll need to argue with the owner of the code that generates the RSA key to make such updates.

Comment: Private keys should be kept private. That means they should be encrypted when stored on disk. Very high value keys should be generated within an [HSM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module). Without knowing more about your environment, it's hard to advise further.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PEMWriter to convert your private key to PEM format that will be accepted by JSch

The following example converts a key returned from KeyStore (JKS)

```
Key privateKey = KeyStore.getKey(privateKeyAlias, keyStorePassword);//get key from JKS
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
PEMWriter pemWriter = new PEMWriter(stringWriter);
pemWriter.writeObject(privateKey);
pemWriter.close();

byte[] privateKeyPEM = stringWriter.toString().getBytes();
```