# Teamcity SSH private key login failed: invalid privatekey

Tags: ssh, teamcity, jsch, teamcity-8.0

I set SSH login which connect from Windows Agent to Linux but TeamCity gives following error.

> [New build problem] com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: invalid privatekey: [B@5543cd

The keypair which generated by SSH Secure Shell has no problem to connect to server.

Similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14276246/jsch-getting-invalid-privatekey-while-trying-to-load-an-rsa-private-key-by-ke) but it's not my programmatic problem but teamcity inner exception.

Note that my problem is not a case of GitHub VCS connectivity issue. just a problem between my Windows TeamCity Agent to CentOS Linux server.

Full stacktrace is as below.

> [Step 6/8] com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: invalid privatekey: [B@5543cd at com.jcraft.jsch.KeyPair.load(KeyPair.java:702) at com.jcraft.jsch.KeyPair.load(KeyPair.java:542) at com.jcraft.jsch.IdentityFile.newInstance(IdentityFile.java:40) at com.jcraft.jsch.JSch.addIdentity(JSch.java:389) at com.jcraft.jsch.JSch.addIdentity(JSch.java:349) at jetbrains.buildServer.deployer.agent.ssh.SSHSessionProvider.initSessionKeyFile(SSHSessionProvider.java:110) at jetbrains.buildServer.deployer.agent.ssh.SSHSessionProvider.(SSHSessionProvider.java:80) at jetbrains.buildServer.deployer.agent.ssh.SSHExecRunner.createBuildProcess(SSHExecRunner.java:26) at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.runner.CallRunnerService.doCreateBuildProcess(CallRunnerService.java:71) at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.runner.CallRunnerService.createBuildProcess(CallRunnerService.java:47) at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.runnerStages.start.CallRunnerStage.doBuildStage(CallRunnerStage.java:47) at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.RunnerStagesExecutor$1.callStage(RunnerStagesExecutor.java:25) at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.RunnerStagesExecutor$1.callStage(RunnerStagesExecutor.java:18) at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.StagesExecutor.callRunStage(StagesExecutor.java:78) at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.StagesExecutor.doStages(StagesExecutor.java:37) at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.RunnerStagesExecutor.doStages(RunnerStagesExecutor.java:18) at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.startStages.steps.RunnerContextExecutor.callRunnerStages(RunnerContextExecutor.java:43) at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.startStages.steps.StepExecutor.processNextStep(StepExecutor.java:25) at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.startStages.steps.ForEachBuildRunnerStage.executeRunnerStep(ForEachBuildRunnerStage.java:138) at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.startStages.steps.ForEachBuildRunnerStage.runStep(ForEachBuildRunnerStage.java:123) at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.startStages.steps.ForEachBuildRunnerStage.executeBuildRunners(ForEachBuildRunnerStage.java:83) at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.startStages.steps.ForEachBuildRunnerStage.doBuildStage(ForEachBuildRunnerStage.java:44) at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.BuildStagesExecutor$1.callStage(BuildStagesExecutor.java:31) at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.BuildStagesExecutor$1.callStage(BuildStagesExecutor.java:24) at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.StagesExecutor.callRunStage(StagesExecutor.java:78) at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.StagesExecutor.doStages(StagesExecutor.java:37) at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.buildStages.BuildStagesExecutor.doStages(BuildStagesExecutor.java:24) at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.BuildRunAction.doStages(BuildRunAction.java:70) at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.BuildRunAction.runBuild(BuildRunAction.java:50) at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.BuildAgentImpl.doActualBuild(BuildAgentImpl.java:263) at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.BuildAgentImpl.access$100(BuildAgentImpl.java:50) at jetbrains.buildServer.agent.impl.BuildAgentImpl$1.run(BuildAgentImpl.java:236) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Comment: Could you edit your question to describe specifically how you generated this key, and what specific file you set Teamcity to read for the key?

Answer (score 13):

For everyone coming here searching for a solution to the "Invalid private key" on Teamcity, the solution is to generate the key with this command:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -m PEM
```

This is pointed out in [this page](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD18/SSH+Keys+Management) of the documentation

Comment: Perfect this done the trick for me. You should get the correct answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, the format of Private Key you are providing is not the one JSCH expects (i.e. OpenSSH).

Similar question and answer is provided here: 
[JSCH - Invalid private key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15332120/jsch-invalid-private-key)

Answer (score 0):

After a considerable amount of time spent on this and running the correct commands and getting the same error of invalid privatekey, I looked up what was JSch looking for? Eventually I found this code that helped me create the key that it wanted and I was able to connect:

```
try {
        com.jcraft.jsch.KeyPair pair = com.jcraft.jsch.KeyPair.genKeyPair(new 
        JSch(), com.jcraft.jsch.KeyPair.RSA);
        ByteArrayOutputStream publicKeyOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ByteArrayOutputStream privateKeyOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        pair.writePublicKey(publicKeyOut, "kamranbhatti");
        pair.writePrivateKey(privateKeyOut);
        String publicKey = new String(publicKeyOut.toByteArray());
        String privateKey = new String(privateKeyOut.toByteArray());
        System.out.println(publicKey);
        System.out.println(privateKey);

    } catch (Exception e) { 

          }
```

I copied the private key to the server and I was able to connect.